# How to evaluate if a data exist in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I have the following code that prints one item per column on the browser.

What I would like to do is in another page when a button is click is to check to see if any instance of that item is found in the page.

Page that prints out item

```
<html>

<head>
  <title> <%= title %></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <% for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <% for(var f=0; f< fields.length; f++) { %>
        <td>
          <%= rows[i][fields[f].name] %>
        </td>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
      <% } %>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Code that should check if item exist in that page

```
$("#checkHashtag").click(function() {
    var hashtag = document.getElementById("codeInput").value;
// Check to see if user enter hashtag exist in that page
if(hashtag == ....**(thats where i need help)**

});
```

Thanks in advance

Below is the data page
[image]
I want to check to see if any instance of that data exist on that page upon button click

Comment: You'll have to be clearer? Do you want to check if there are any TR's or TD's outputted in the table ?

Comment: your code produces no element with ID `codeInput` or even `checkHashtag` - so you're fighting a losing battle from the get go

Comment: I;ve added an update in my initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on your comments above, if you are trying to check if the hash is in the DOM on a page you are currently on, you could do something like this:

```js
$("#checkHashtag").click(function() {
    var hashtag = document.getElementById("codeInput").value;
if(hashtag) {
  var cells = $('td');
  cells.each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == hash) {
    console.log('foo'); // Do something if hash is found
  }

});
```

If you need to access the list of values from multiple pages, then storing them in the DOM isn't the best strategy. You could either create an endpoint to get the values via an ajax request, or the simpler, less elegant solution would be to use you templates to put the values you need in a script tag on every page so you can simply access the variable on the client side.

```html
<script>
  var hashes = [1234, 1235, 1236];
</script>
```

Comment: Youre right storing in dom isnt the best strategy for what i am trying to do. I have created a new question here, and hopefully you could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861219/check-mysql-query-based-on-an-input-value-using-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

If there is a value in `var hashtag = document.getElementById("codeInput").value;` it could have a value which might evaluate to true. So you can simply do:

```
if(hashtag) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @John your initial post is incomplete. It does not include the element that has the ID "codeInput".

Comment: well simply put the element that has an id is just an input field that the user types in, and then when they click on the button thats when i am trying to check on another page lets say /hashtag if there is an instance of this item that exist

Comment: When the user clicks the button you want to check for a value in another page?

Comment: correct sir, in the /hashtag page all of the data is there and i am trying to see if what the user enters matches any of that data

Comment: Well in the "other" page you would run the code provided above.

Comment: except there more items on that page that checks the value and there may be other pages that checks the user hashtag, which why i have dedicated one page to display all of the hashtag and in every other page that needs to check if the user hashtag is valid would check to see if the value is in the /hashtag page